# Rewrite url in apache configuration

Tags: apache, url-rewriting

Need help about how to rewrite url in apache.

How to rewrite URL A to URL B.
URL A: project1.domainname.com

URL B: domainname.com/sites/project1

Below is my configuration, but not worked:

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond {HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.domainname\.com$

RewriteRule ^(.*).domainname.com$ "http://domainname.com/sites/$1/"

please leave your idea, thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to rewrite `project1.domainname.com` —> `domainname.com/sites/project1` is

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.domainname\.com$
RewriteRule ^$ http://domainname.com/sites/%1
```

Add a trailing slash to the rule if necessary.